# How to change default tab indent size when creating file with ionic generate command?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic-cli

I was trying to figure out the way i can change the default tab indent size of my TS files generated by `Ionic CLI`

Whenever i run  `ionic generate` command it creates the file with tab indention of 2 spaces

How can i make it to default 4?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible to configure within the ionic-cli. But it's easy to change the defaults for .ts files in your text editor/IDE.

Usually there is an .editorconfig file (in the root of the project) for this. Read more about [here](http://editorconfig.org/).

Comment: But still, the `ionic generate` command will create the file with tab indention of 2 spaces :/

Comment: does .editorconfig file has to do something with the 'ionic generate'?, i don't think so..

Comment: @powercoder23 I didn't say that .editorconfig changes the way ionic generator behaves. What I meant is that .editorconfig can set this settings for the developer (and other team members) when they open/edit files. It's kind of a "workaround" as long as neither ionic-clic nor even angular-cli has this option.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I use sublimetext and the problem is that it automatically determines the indentation level by analizing the file created by Ionic, so it will always set the file to use indentation level 2, despite of you having tab size set to 4 by default.  So, you need to remember to reset the indentation level to 4 every time you open a file generated by Ionic the first time.  That's the part that is annoying and that is not affected by any configuration on the text editor itself.